# GRPC. Testing Context

Tags: python, testing, pytest, grpc

Currently we able to test positive cases following way:

```
class AuthServer(auth_grpc.AuthServicer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Initializing auth server..")
        super(AuthServer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def register(self, request, context):
        return auth_messages.registerResponse(uuid="Test")
```

With `pytest` fixtures looking following way:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def server():
    return AuthServer()


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def context():
    return DummyGRPCTestContext()
```

In test case environment accessed following way:

```
def test_user_registration(server, context, user):
    request = auth_messages.registerRequest(**user)
    result = server.register(request, context)
    print("RESULT %s " % result)
```

However, if we want test negative case and changing grpc servicer method to following:

```
def register(self, request, context):
    context.set_code(grpc.StatusCode.ALREADY_EXISTS)
    context.set_details("User already exists")
    return auth_messages.registerResponse()
```

We're failing in errors, related to dummy context.

Where we can get grpc context, that can be easily plugged into test environment?

Contexts like [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/de110af820a912ae926a1a9659a385b6a972f84d/src/python/grpcio_testing/grpc_testing/_server/_rpc.py) one look complex and not ready for plug and test.

Comment: Possible to get a sample repo with minimal test code reproducing the issue?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, good idea. Will do, but not right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`grpc.ServicerContext` is just an interface](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/5eb6148ab4e95ea472af2033bd976317992fe18f/src/python/grpcio/grpc/__init__.py#L932); within your test code you should be able to write your own implementation of it and pass that to your servicer under test.

It's true that at this time we don't provide in `grpc_testing` a `grpc.ServicerContext` implementation ready to be used by tests and passed to systems under test, but it's also not entirely clear that we could provide one that would be simply implemented and also valuable to a large number of tests. There's a large behavioral space of how servicers under test use `grpc.ServicerContext` objects and there's another large behavioral space of how authors write tests of servicers.

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes, I've ended with idea of mocking parts of context, that we use in business logic. And we can have several contexts during testing. Also context that is ready to use - will not help to test things like interceptors - so we have several "integration" tests, that have full grpc server with all servicers in fixture. Unfortunally unable to share it as answer, may be later will create micro-framework.